# Cloud Run to Cloud Run API service gives Error: connect ECONNREFUSED <google IP> (Node JS)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, axios, nestjs, google-cloud-run

We are running two APIs on two different Google Cloud Cloud Run services which call each other through regular HTTP requests. However, when load increases we are getting "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED "  errors. The service performing the requests is written in NodeJS and uses Axios to perform the requests.

Any recommendations on how to troubleshoot/resolve this issue? The stacktrace that we see is:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED <google IP>:443
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect (net.js:1107)
```

it seems that the request is dropped before it is handled by the HTTP server of the second API service. Could this be a Google infrastructure issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This appears to be a Google Frontend issue. If your app was failing, a different error would be reported. In which regions are the services running? Create an Issue Tracker here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley. We are deployed on region "europe-west1".

Comment: What do you mean by the load increase? How many concurrent request do you have? And what about the CPU and Memory usage of your Cloud Run service?